# How to install istio on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

im install default k8s setup

kubeadm init + flannel + istio in helm

Deploy nginx pod in default namespace

but describe deployment have error:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://PODIP:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 10.244.0.58:15021: connect: connection refused
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luHP7.png)

Im not undestand what is it , and i get logs istio proxy and error:

```
2023-10-24T11:33:41.950353Z     warn    HTTP request failed: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: no route to host

2023-10-24T11:33:41.950411Z     warn    Could not unmarshal response: unexpected end of JSON input:

2023-10-24T11:33:45.022209Z     warn    HTTP request failed: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-08-15": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: no route to host

2023-10-24T11:33:45.022359Z     warn    Could not unmarshal response: unexpected end of JSON input:
```

Im check witch nc in nginx pod and
10.244.0.58:15021 - open

chck in master node curl - 200

im not understend who doin next